# PHP - Shell_exec and exec returning false when ran

Tags: php, ubuntu

I've done some extensive research on this topic. But I found nothing. It seems when I run shell_exec() it always returns false. Even when the output is true.

PHP script:

```
$tmp1 = exec("/var/www/html/online/files/test.sh 2>&1");
```

test.sh Bash script:

```
var=$(screen -ls | awk -F'[. ]' '/.onoff/ {print $1}')
if [ -z "$var" ]; then
  echo "false"
else
  echo "true"
fi
```

It's testing the screen PID for a screen called 'onoff' which was running at the time of being ran, yet still returns false. Even when I use the command in PuTTY it returns true.

Here are the permissions of the files:

```
root@s94029:~# ls -la /var/www/html/online
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec 18 12:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Dec 18 09:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 18 11:54 files
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  221 Dec 18 04:59 index.css
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4310 Dec 18 12:55 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  417 Dec 18 06:40 servers.php
root@s94029:~# ls -la /var/www/html/online/files
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 18 11:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 18 12:34 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  115 Dec 18 11:54 test1.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  114 Dec 18 11:54 test.sh
```

Any help would be nice!

Thanks!

Comment: Owner is root, that explains it.. On a side note, `exec` returns false, not your command. Do a `===` check.

Comment: Even after setting the owner to www-data, it doesn't work. And where exactly should I put a '==='?

Answer (score 1):

try `exec($command, $output, $status)`
check output and status variable. non zero in status variable is error. zero is success.

After doing this check ownership of the file... add www-data (apache) user to the ownership of the file if you still face problem.

```
exec('/var/www/html/online/files/test.sh 2>&1', $output, $status);

print_r($output);
echo $status;
```

Comment: When I use your suggestion, none of them are set. Could you give an example, I feel I'm using it wrong.

Comment: Here is the output of the page:

Ahh yes, here is the output:

    Output: Array
    Status: 0

Comment: I forgot to add the code things,

`Output: Array
Status: 0`

Comment: Here is print_r($output):
`Array ( [0] => false )`

Comment: this means your script is running and returning "false" string from the script

Comment: Even after setting it to www-data and back to root with 777 perms it doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean does not work your code is working fine... php can run your script and get status zero... this means everything is fine just you need to pass yoir parameter to the script that i have not passed to the script. wait see updated code above

Comment: I may have not been to clear on the subject, when I run
`$tmp1 = exec("/var/www/html/online/files/test.sh 2>&1");`
I also run
`echo $tmp1;`
which is what returns false. However I don't understand why this returns false (even with shell_exec) when the output is true.
Here is the output from the latest code:
`Output: Array ( [0] => false )
Status: 0`

Comment: It doesn't return anything without, something about dumping a variable onto another variable because it only reads one variable. I believe.